# Correct MIME Type for favicon.ico?

Tags: html, browser, mime-types, favicon

According to the **Internet Assigned Numbers Authority** (IANA), all .ico file falls under the MIME type `image/vnd.microsoft.icon`. ([Source](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image/vnd.microsoft.icon))

E.g.
`<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="favicon.ico" />`

However, savvy internet guru, **Paul Irish**, claims this is wrong, and that it would actually be `image/x-icon`. ([Source](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/commit/37b5fec090d00f38de64b591bcddcb205aadf8ee))

E.g.
`<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />`

I know you can get away with not including a "type" for .ico files, but if you were going to include one, which should it be? Are there actually any problems with serving it as official IANA type?

Comment: Note of caution: `favicon.ico` files might not be true ".ico" files.  My corporate site uses a png (named "favicon.ico") and serves it with the "image/png" type.  Serving it with either of the ".ico" types mentioned here were BOTH wrong, as it caused the browser to misinterpret!

Answer (score 260, accepted):

When you're serving an .ico file to be used as a favicon, it doesn't matter. All major browsers recognize both mime types correctly. So you could put:

```
<!-- IE -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<!-- other browsers -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

or the same with `image/vnd.microsoft.icon`, and it will work with all browsers.

Note: There is no IANA specification for the MIME-type `image/x-icon`, so it does appear that it is a little more unofficial than `image/vnd.microsoft.icon`.

The only case in which there is a difference is if you were trying to use an .ico file in an `<img>` tag (which is pretty unusual).
Based on previous testing, some browsers would only display .ico files as images when they were served with the MIME-type `image/x-icon`. More recent tests show: Chromium, Firefox and Edge are fine with both content types, IE11 is not. If you can, just avoid using `ico` files as images, use `png`.

Comment: I didn't choose anything anywhere, I tried to explain the two usecases: 1 - used as favicon (doesn't matter which mime type), 2 - used as an img within webpage (IE only displays it correctly with mimetype image/x-icon).

Comment: You say, you can use .ico files in `<img src=''>` provided they are served as **image/x-image** by the webserver. You then say if you're going to use .ico files as images in HTML pages you should set the MIME type to **image/x-icon**.

Comment: Great. At least it makes sense now! I'm not really interested in serving .ico files as images within a website, though. The question is specifically about using .ico file as favicons. If you rephrase your answer, that would be much more helpful. Thanks.

Comment: According to wikipedia, image/x-icon was just made up by Microsoft, image/vnd.microsoft.icon is registered with IANA (but not registered by Microsoft themselves).

Comment: FWIW, Google uses image/x-icon for their [favicon](http://www.google.com/favicon.ico).

Comment: From a very quick test on my local server, it seems that Apache uses `image/x-icon` by default when serving ICO files.

Comment: FWIW, Microsoft uses `image/x-icon` for their [favicon](https://www.microsoft.com/favicon.ico?v2).

Answer (score 61):

I think the root for this confusion is well explained in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29) wikipedia article.

> While the IANA-registered MIME type for ICO files is
>   image/vnd.microsoft.icon, it was submitted to IANA in 2003 by a third
>   party and is not recognised by Microsoft software, which uses
>   image/x-icon instead.

If even the inventor of the ICO format does not use the official MIME type, I will use `image/x-icon`, too.

Comment: Finally an answer! However it's still the IANA-registered MIME type... even if Microsoft themselves don't use it. Weird.

Answer (score 10):

I have noticed that when using `type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"`, the favicon fails to appear when the browser is not connected to the internet.
But `type="image/x-icon"` works whether the browser can connect to the internet, or not.
When developing, at times I am not connected to the internet.